# Install apache2 on ubuntu 11.10 after installing php 5.2.17 issue

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

Recently I immigrate to Ubuntu and everything was going good to I configuring and compiling PHP 5.2.17 on Ubuntu before I install apache2.

Now when I try install apache2 it installs successfully but unfortunately during start apache2 I get this error:

```
[crit] Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.  You need to recompile PHP.
Pre-configuration failed
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

Any ideas for fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try deleting all the apache2 folders from /etc/ and /var/ folders.
  Then remove apache and its dependencies

  `sudo apt-get --purge remove apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils apache2.2-common`
- Then try installing apache again:

  `sudo apt-get install apache2`

  check the 127.0.0.1 to get "It works!" message ;) or check apache status by

  `service apache2 status`
- now go with recompiling php 5.2.17 with fast-cgi enabled using this (edit it as you wish, this is mine) configurations options:

  `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php-5.1.6 --with-config-file-path=/etc/php-5.1.6  --disable-ipv6 --with-zlib --enable-bcmath --with-bz2 --with-curl --enable-exif --enable-ftp --with-gd --with-ttf --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-imap-ssl --enable-mbstring --with-mhash --with-mysql --with-mysqli --enable-pcntl --with-pdo-mysql --with-pdo-sqlite --enable-shmop --enable-soap --enable-sockets --enable-sqlite-utf8 --with-xmlrpc --with-xsl --with-pear --enable-fastcgi`
- and then make & make install it. That should do the work

Answer (score 1):

If you compiled PHP before compiling Apache, that might be where your problem is. Could you post your config.nice files from both PHP and Apache? That might give a better idea of where your problem is.

-EDIT- Usually, when compiling PHP with Apache, you have to use the --with-apache flag, or --with-apxs, which is part of Apache. That might be a good place to look.

Comment: Yeah it is for sure happened by installing PHP just before apache as @fkniya implied.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need about installing Apache2+PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

Core options: http://php.net/manual/en/configure.about.php

And, finally, why don't you use `deb` packages?